# Python SciPy: optimization issue fmin_cobyla : one constraint is not respected

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have the below optimisation problem:

The objective function is quite simple: given a vector `SPREAD`, I try to find the vector `W` to maximize `sum(W.SPREAD)`.

As an example, in dimension 3, this mean I try to maximize `w1 x spread1 + w2 x spread2 + w3 x spread3`.

Plus, I have three constraints `c1, c2 & c3` not on `W`, but on a `POS` vector where `POS = W2POS(W)`.

As an example, in dimension 3, contraints are:

1. `|pos1 + pos2 + pos3| < 5`
2. `|pos1| + |pos2| + |pos3| < 500`
3. `Max(pos1, pos2, pos3) < 5`

I wrote the below code which perform some optimization, however, constraints 3 is not respected. How can I solve this problem respecting my constraints?

I wrote the below code:

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin_cobyla
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def W2POS(W, PRICE, BETA):
    POS = (PRICE * BETA).T.dot(W)
    return POS

def objective(W, SPREAD, sign = 1):
    er = sum((W * SPREAD.T).sum())
    return sign * er

def c1(x, *args):
    """ abs(sum(c)) < 500    """
    POS = W2POS(x,args[0], args[1]) 
    return POS.apply(abs).sum()

def c2(x, *args):
    """ abs(sum()) < 5    """
    POS = W2POS(x,args[0], args[1]) 
    return 5. - abs(POS.sum())

def c3(x, *args):
    """ abs(max(pos)) < 5   """
    POS = W2POS(x,args[0], args[1]) 
    return 5. - POS.apply(abs).max()

# optim
W0 = np.zeros(shape=(len(BETA), 1))
sign = -1
W = fmin_cobyla(objective, W0, cons = [c1, c2, c3], args=(SPREAD,sign), 
                consargs=(PRICE, BETA), maxfun=100, rhobeg = 0.02).T
print 'Solution:', W
args = [PRICE, BETA]
pos = W2POS(W.T,args[0], args[1]) 
print 'c1 < 5:', abs(pos.sum())[0]
print 'c2 < 500:', pos.apply(abs).sum()[0]
print 'c3 < 5:', pos.apply(abs).apply(max)[0]
```

You can play with some dummy data that will illustrate c3 being not respected with this code : http://pastebin.com/gjbeePgt

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation in the original Fortran 77 file *cobyla2.f* (available in [this](http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/other_software/COBYLA2.tar.gz) package), lines 38 and 39, it is stated:

> C1,C2,...,CM denote the constraint functions that should become nonnegative eventually, at least to the precision of RHOEND

If I interpret the *scipy* API documentation for [fmin_cobyla](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_cobyla.html) correctly, `RHOEND` is by default set to *1.0E-4*.

If the observed constraint violations are indeed less than `RHOEND` but still unacceptably large, a simple solution to the issue would be to incorporate the value of `RHOEND` in the constraint formulations, i.e.

```
C[i] + RHOEND >= 0
```

---

In this particular case, it *does* appear like the constraint violation is larger than `RHOEND`, which has been thoroughly illustrated by a [new test case in the *scipy* repository](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/tests/test_cobyla.py#L46), constructed by Pauli Virtanen, and corresponding to the above question.

To avoid constraint violation in this particular case, the solution appears to be to start the optimization with a smaller value on `RHOBEG`, for example *0.01*.